# how to find a finite set of vectors that spans W

Tags: linear-algebra

Let W be the set of all vectors (x1 x2 x3 x4 x5) in R5 which
satisfy
2x1
x1
9x1
x2 +4
3
x3
+2
3
x3
x4
= 0
x5 = 0
3x2 +6x3 3x4 3x5= 0
Find a finite set of vectors that spans W.

Comment: Can you rewrite the equations? I think you made some errors writing them and they are difficult to understand

Comment: Also, this is formulated as a "please do my homework" question, which is not well-received on this site. Please include your own thoughts.